# convert xml record to json recusively

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, recursion

I have the following object

```
type xmlrecord = {
   tag:string;
   value?: string;
   children?:xmlrecord[];
}
```

and the text and children parameters are mutually exclusive.
i would like a function that converts the following format in json format like

```
const obj = convertTOjson(xmlrecord);
```

and then i could do something like:

```
const value = obj.tag;
```

or

```
const value2 = obj.children[0].tag;
```

Comment: This looks to be neither about XML or JSON, you're just restructuring objects containing arrays containing objects. Have you tried anything so far? This isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.